# Can I say "Current video file formats"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I often need on other StackExchange sites to talk about file formats.

I believe that *current* means like *recent*.

Can I say *current video file format* to talk about file format often used, when it's the regularity which is important and not the novelty?

Comment: *Recent* means *not long ago*. *Current* means *right now*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Current" video file format refers to the format the file is in at the time of writing. If you want to talk about file formats that are regularly used, use "common", "standard", or "default". Or if it's your own preference, not an industry preference, use "preferred" or "habitual".

- "The current video file format" -> the format the file is in right now
- "The standard video file format" -> the format most files are generally in
- "The preferred video file format" -> the format you or your team or product prefers